# Nontrivial conditions under which $x+y+z$ divides $1 - xyz$

Tags: nt.number-theory

For any nonzero integers $(x, y, z)$ such that $x+y+z$ divides $1 - xyz$., it is easy to verify that $\gcd(x+y, z) = 1$.

But what are the nontrivial conditions such that the divisibility holds ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by nontrivial, but if $(x,y,z)$ is a permutation of $(1,n,n^2)$ then the divisibility holds.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586758/conditions-under-which-abc-divides-1-abc

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer.

Let $p_2(x,y,z)=1-xyz$ and $p_1(x,y,z)=x+y+z$.

You want $p_2/p_1$ to be integer for integers $x,y,z$.

Let $X=y^2 z + yz^2 - y - z + 1$.

$p_2(X,y,z)/p_1(X,y,z)=1-y z$, so $x$ exists for
all $y,z$, s.t. $X+y+z \ne 0$.

---

For the exceptional set, we have $X+y+z=y^2z+yz^2+1=0$. The *rational* solutions
are $y=1/2\,{\frac {-{z}^{2}+\sqrt {{z}^{4}-4\,z}}{z}}$
and $y=-1/2\,{\frac {{z}^{2}+\sqrt {{z}^{4}-4\,z}}{z}}$.

This means $z^4-4z=t^2$ for rational $z,t$.

This is genus $1$ curve and unless I am mistaken, it
is birationally equivalent to the Weierstrass model
$v^2=u^3+16$, which have finitely many rational solutions,
since it it is rank $0$ according to sage.